# I want save the userName as unique in db using express and mongoose but it save same userNaame as multiple time in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongoose

here is user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const {Schema}= mongoose;

const userSchema= new Schema({
    userName:{
        type:String,
        required :true,
       unique:true
       },
        
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true},
    role:{
        type:[
            {
                type:String,
                enum:["user","admin"],
                default:["user"]
            }
        ]
    }
},{timestamps:true})

const User= mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
module.exports = User;
```

i have used unique validation key of mongoose type still problem occur

Comment: MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.

Comment: Thanks @Sain Pradeep. This is violated becoz of collection is already existed.